# How to navigate to the .pdf file by using wpf datagrid hyperlink?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, hyperlink, wpf-controls

I have a WPF datagrid which has a hyperlink column. The hyperlinks are of PDF documents which I have on system(not in a specific folder).
How do i write a code to navigate to the document?
When I click on the hyperlink it gives an error "Can not navigate to application resource".
How do i resolve this error Please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to open it in pdf reader application?

Comment: Yes. I want to open it in adobe reader.

Comment: Fast way to do it - is to save the pdf file to the local storage, and run it using Process.Start() method. if it is not solution for you, try to find how to run adobe reader with parameters.